# Adjusting the P-values-Need some advice

Tags: anova

*Dear All,
I have a data set with 10 continuous variables and 11 categorical variables. The ANOA test (for six continuous variables) and the Kruskal-Wallis test (for four continuous variables) were applied to the BMI levels (with three levels). Chi-square test was applied to categorical variables versus BMI levels. (so we have 6 anova tests, 4 Kruskal–Wallis  tests, 10 chi square tests).  Then Multiple comparison tests were performed on variables with significant p-values. **How should the Pvalues for this project be adjusted**?*  *Forexample, If I wish to utilize the Bonferroni correction, how many tests should I alter and how should they be adjusted?*